# How to print a table from a list with numbers and strings in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print a table from my current code which only outputs a list so far however I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
{'judy': 1, 'dean': 1, 'andrew': 2, 'sam': 4, 'fred': 2}
```

I would like to output a list in this format when the input is 3:

```
4 sam
2 andrew fred
1 dean judy
```

or like this if the input is 2 (all ties need to be in alphabetical order also):

```
4 sam
2 andrew fred
```

This is my code so far which only outputs a list:

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")

with open('stream.txt','r') as f:
    tweetlist = [r.split()[0] for r in f if "DM" not in r and "RT" not 
    in r]

tweet_counter = {}
for tweet in tweetlist:
    if tweet in tweet_counter:
        tweet_counter[tweet] += 1
    else:
        tweet_counter[tweet] = 1

popular_users = sorted(tweet_counter, key = tweet_counter.get, reverse 
= True)
top = popular_users[:x]
top.sort()
print(tweet_counter)
```

thanks in advance, all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `collections.Counter` object that counts things so your first loop:

```
tweet_counter = {}
for tweet in tweetlist:
    if tweet in tweet_counter:
        tweet_counter[tweet] += 1
    else:
        tweet_counter[tweet] = 1
```

can be replaced by:

```
from collections import Counter
tweet_counter = Counter(tweetlist)
```

`Counter.most_common()` returns `(key, value)` in value order and then you can use python's powerful iterator algebra (`itertools`) to get the required result. First use `itertools.groupby()` to group the values together and `itertools.islice()` to get the number you need, e.g.:

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

def print_table(tc, n):
    name, value = op.itemgetter(0), op.itemgetter(1)
    for k, g in it.islice(it.groupby(tc.most_common(), value), n):
        print(k, ' '.join(sorted(map(name, g))))

In []:
print_table(tweet_counter, 2)

Out[]:
4 sam
2 andrew fred

In []:
print_table(tweet_counter, 3)

Out[]:
4 sam
2 andrew fred
1 dean judy
```

Comment: is there any way to make sure this prints without the brackets?

Comment: Which brackets?

Comment: I get  (4, 'sam')
(2, 'andrew fred')
(1, 'dean judy')

Comment: Ahh, you are using Py2, you can either just remove the parens to `print`, e.g. `print k, ' '.join(sorted(map(name, g)))` or put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top your program. In Py3, `print()` is a function.

Comment: is there any way i could just convert my program into python 3? how do i check which version i am on? (I'm using pycharm on mac)

Comment: Add the `from __future__ ...` and it will make the program py2 and py3 compatible. How to make `pycharm` use `python3` is not something I can help - I don't use `pycharm` - but I'm sure a quick google will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry to be a pain but is there anyway I could change your solution to print the top x names instead of lines? So for example an input of 3 would print 4 sam, 2 andrew fred

Comment: `for k, g in it.groupby(tc.most_common(n)):`

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately all i get is 

    ('sam', 4) sam
    ('andrew', 2) andrew
    ('fred', 2) fred

Any ideas on what to do?